# All Input check box and sorting function of a table coupled together

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table having all check box and sorting function. When I click the all check box, the sorting function of first column is activating. Its like both functions are coupled together. I tried to decouple both, but not a success

**Code**

```
<table id="example" class="table" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 35%;">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="chkall">
                                    Url
                                </th>
                                <th>Organization</th>
                                <th>Urls Pending Validation</th>
                                <th>Validated Event Units</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="urlTd">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault"> 
                                    https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300
                                </td>
                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="urlTd">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                                    https://picsum.photos/id/870/200/300?grayscale&blur=2
                                </td>
                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                <td>61</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
<table>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkall").change(function (event) {
        $('.form-check-input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', event.target.checked);
        });
    });
    $("#chkall2").change(function (event) {
        $('.form-check-input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', event.target.checked);
        });
    });
    $("#chkall3").change(function (event) {
        $('.form-check-input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', event.target.checked);
        });
    });
});
```

**[image]**

In the figure when I click the all select check box then ascending/descending sorting is also activated. I have 3 such similar subpages and each have a table like this.

**Pages**
[image]

Also when I select the all select check box in one subpage, then all select chkboxes in all three pages are selected. Apologies for the question being not clear.

Comment: Besides being invalid HTML, it's a bad habit to use `#id` (especially using a crutch like jQuery) unless it's for a very specific reason (ex. form control `#id` and label `[for]` association). There are two checkboxes sharing the same `#id` of #`flexCheckDefault`. Having duplicated `#id` will result in unexpected behavior (like firering off 2 event handlers when only expected one to trigger). But looking at the OP code...I think the problem doesn't stem from dupe `#id`s....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if this is your expected behaviour, but

```
$("#chkall").change(function(event) {
    $('.form-check-input').each(function() {
    
        $(this).prop('checked', event.target.checked);
    });
});

$('.form-check-input').change(function(event) {
        if (!event.target.checked)
            $("#chkall").prop('checked', false);
});
```

Uncheck the "Url" #chkall option when an element is unchecked

Now you have jQuery code apllied to $("#chkall") , $("#chkall2") , $("#chkall3")

Which call the IDs of 3 DOM elements, of which 2 aren't in the code you included. Namely : elements with ID #chkall1 and #chkall2

Beside, you talk about a sorting function, but I don't see anything like such in your code. It makes the question quite confusign.

It's unclear what you mean by "sorting function". Do you have a sorting function applied to the first column of your table which you haven't included in your snippet?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I think i added tmore clarity required for the question.